# Redundant formatted date field

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

We are developing a web application which is hosted on Appengine Flexible environment and we are using datastore as our backend. In our scenario we do multiple inserts for the same day and when we pull data for the day we need to pull all records for that day which is very straight forward. One of our Devs added a formatted date filed YYYYMMDD in addition to DateAdded which is Datetime.Now.
This is to make the Reads easy. We are only doing inserts. An update to any record will be a new insert for auditing purposes. Need suggestion if adding a redundant date(YYYYMMDD) field is ok and how costly this would be on the datastore. This field is a string and I personally think this is ok. But wanted to get advice on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, you don't need another property to hold the formatted date, but it does make your query look simpler. In other words, you could use the original DateTime property, where you store the entity creation timestamp, to find all entities for a given date or date range.

Using a String property with YYYYMMDD requires a simple query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyKind WHERE MyProperty='20170209'
```

On the other hand, if you want to use the original DateTime property, your query would be something like this -

```
SELECT * FROM MyKind WHERE MyProperty >= DATETIME('2017-02-09T00:00:00.000000Z') AND MyProperty < DATETIME('2017-02-10T00:00:00.000000Z')
```

Either approach is fine.